# Is it proper to use the word "bandwidth" as it relates to time allotment?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, time, technical

I'm a web developer and I've often heard other technical and developer types say:

> Sorry, I don't have the bandwidth to take on your project at this time.

I started using the term myself and thought it was an excellent way of expressing that you don't have enough time for something. Recently, I used this term with a potential client and he interpreted it as meaning that I still had a dialup internet connection so would not be able to handle his needs.

I then realized this is where the term originated from so I guess I could understand his confusion. Should I use the word only in specific circles of people that I know will understand it?

Comment: I'm surprised your client didn't get the reference. I may be living in a bubble, but my impression is that don't understand that figurative use of *bandwidth* are way out of the loop. Nevertheless, you were turning him down, so whatever he understood is not all that critical. My guess is, dealing with him would be a pain in any case.

Comment: Robusto, thanks for your insight, I did turn him down because all my developer inner warning bells went off in preliminary dealings with him.

Comment: I've never come across this usage before, even if it's common among geeks (until now, I thought I was one myself!). So I'm voting to close as "too localised"

Comment: Common usage of the term this way has been safe up until the time when everyone had another universally understood reason for using the term. At that point, it became ambiguous. Ambiguities can be resolved by context, but your context may be different from that of the person you are conversing with.

Comment: May I recommend the good old-fashioned non-confusing word *capacity*.

Comment: Never use a euphemism where the simple truth is expected.

Comment: To answer your frain ... yes. The meaning you're using is not widely known. Like Fumblefingers, I think of myself as tech savvy and I'v never heard it noted that way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I happen to find this use of the word irritating, but there is no doubt that it is widely used, at least in technology companies.

As you indicate, it will be misunderstood in some quarters, which might be a good reason for avoiding it.

The question of whether or not it is "proper" is meaningless, unless you define the particular arbiter of manners who you want to defer to. There is no authority for the English language.

Comment: +1 for: *the question of whether or not is is "proper" is meaningless, unless you define the particular arbiter of manners who you want to defer to.  There is no authority for the English language.*  Can I quote you on that?  Even better, can I pretend that I wrote it myself?

Comment: @Pitarou: be my guest!

Answer (score 12):

Bandwidth, literally, is the amount of data that can be passed along a communications channel in a given period of time. On the other hand, in **business jargon**, it is sometimes used to refer to **the resources needed to complete a task or project**. Clear language is important for clear communication. So it may be better to avoid **jargon**  if you are not sure they will understand you.

Comment: +1 that's interesting, any references to documents in which it would be used in this sense?

Comment: @Vladtn,  especially in IT environments, bandwidth may also be used to refer to "data allocation"- the amount of data that can be used in total. I think, this usage evolves into "the resources needed to do something"  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth).

Answer (score 3):

Lacking bandwidth is generally interpreted as lacking resources. In your case, you mean time, but this is not a given, so it is likely to cause confusion.

Also, "lacking bandwidth" is a term the programmers in my group use to derisively describe folks with diminished processing capabilities.

I would have interpreted this statement to mean that you were too technologically (or cognitively) primitive to be able to complete my request, not that you simply couldn't schedule it.

Answer (score 2):

"Bandwidth" is an expression inferring available "processing power" or "throughput"; how much you can do in a given time. Thus, it is perfectly acceptable in my mind to use the term figuratively to refer to your business' ability to take on more work, roughly synonymous to "manpower" or "man-hours".

Answer (score 2):

Bandwidth was originally used to mean the width, in Hz, of an Electromagnetic Spectrum "band" (a contiguous interval of frequencies) that is allocated to a particular use.

Wider frequency bands allow more "channels" of data to flow through. For example, the US FM Radio band is allocated from 87.5 to 108.0 MHz. Each FM radio channel [occupies about 100 kHz of this band.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aRDS_vs_DirectBand_FM-spectrum2.svg)

This term was borrowed for use in telecommunications to represent the total capacity of any channel, regardless of whether it was utilizing a specific EM band or not.  (Cable and Satellite communications do use EM bands for their data, whereas dial-up internet uses sound waves transmitted over copper.)

Now, if we think of the tasks that we perform throughout the day as consuming separate "bands" of time, then the term makes perfect sense.  Being "out of bandwidth" would indicate that you do not have enough unallocated "bands of time" in your day to complete the task.

Using the term *bandwidth* to describe *time* maps more closely (in my opinion) to the original definition, than the current definition describing data capacity does.

Comment: "dial-up internet uses sound waves transmitted over copper." -- really?

Comment: @Kris:  Yes really.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iHW1ho8L7V8

Comment: Any other references would be most welcome, esp., text. Just curious.

Comment: @Kris - does this help any? An acoustic coupler is a bit archaic but does nicely demonstrate the data-as-noise paradigm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_coupler

Comment: @Kris - and you have to watch the video linked in the Wiki article if you're at all curious to see one of them. It's a beautiful thing.. Okay, perhaps I'm mad, but still, awesome acoustic coupler demo.. http://hackaday.com/2009/05/27/1964-300baud-modem-surfs-the-web/

Comment: @tanantish Tx. But wait! We all know the acoustic coupling tech. I was actually asking if he meant by 'sound waves over copper', something exactly like those kids' "phones" using a string to carry sound waves.  You don't seem to have noticed that in the answer above.

Comment: @Kris - my bad.. and hmm.. never tried it with actual copper wire, I think when I was a kidlet, we had naught but string and dodgy cans. Wonder how it'd go? :)

Comment: "dial-up internet uses sound waves transmitted over copper." - well, you could put it that way, but it's a little misleading. The 'sound' is actually an electrical signal in the audio band, designed to pass over a telephone system that was itself designed to transmit the human voice (again converted to electrical form)

Answer (score 2):

Claude Shannon’s Information Theory developed the concept of bandwidth.  Shannon’s information formula calculates the maximum rate that data can be *sent without error* (Hardesty, 2010) (Shannon, 1948, pp. 379-423, 623-656).

Bandwidth describes communication rather than time.  Latency may be a better synthesis for personal time in regard to networking.

The situation is ironic because the *client's interpretation was correct*.  Use of "bandwidth" as a reference of personal time projects ignorance (please don't do it).

I recommend you refrain from using any slang when working with clients.

Answer (score 0):

From the ways I have seen it used, it means "cognitive force," in the sense of a high level of cognitive abilities being used per unit of time.

It is used in analogy to a network's ability to carry bytes of data per unit of time.

Answer (score 0):

Extra bandwidth explanation:

Simply means you have the extra capacity to work on addition projects given the same time constraints. A very interesting American term!

From a European.